# Initializing objects in GoLang - Heap/stack does that concept exist?

Tags: go

I just started with GoLang. I have noticed there are some initializations like this

```
agentUi := &f.Foo{
        Reader:      os.Stdin,
        Writer:      os.Stdout,
        ErrorWriter: os.Stderr,
    }
```

Coming from a c++ background , I am under the impression the reason above was done because the developer wanted to create a pointer agentUi instead of an object where he could have done something like this

```
agentUi := f.Foo{
        Reader:      os.Stdin,
        Writer:      os.Stdout,
        ErrorWriter: os.Stderr,
    }
```

so basically making sure that the object is still valid after the scope ends.In short create the object on the heap instead of the stack.
Is that correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go does not allow direct control over where the memory you use is allocated.

If you aren't using references, the memory is allocated from the stack.

If you are passing references around, the compiler does escape analysis in order to try to allocate from the stack, but failing that, the memory is allocated on the heap.

You can use `-gcflags '-m -l'` to see escape analysis for your program.

```
go run -gcflags '-m -l' main.go
```

For instance, verifying escape analisys on the program below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", work())
}

type Foo struct {
    Reader      io.Reader
    Writer      io.Writer
    ErrorWriter io.Writer
}

func work() *Foo {
    agentUi := &Foo{
        Reader:      os.Stdin,
        Writer:      os.Stdout,
        ErrorWriter: os.Stderr,
    }
    return agentUi
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run -gcflags '-m -l' main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:20:13: &Foo{...} escapes to heap
./main.go:10:12: ... argument does not escape
&{0xc00000e010 0xc00000e018 0xc00000e020}
```

Comment: "If you aren't using references, the memory is allocated from the stack." Go doesn't have references and if you use "reference" as "pointer" it's still false as there is not even a guarantee that there _is_ a stack (or a heap). This stack/heap allocation stuff is an implementation detail of a certain compiler and changes frequently.

Comment: @Volker By references I meant reference types, like pointers, slices, maps. Of course the details can change, and there might be an implementation without stack/heap. But today the main Go implementation do perform escape analisys to choose between stack and heap.

Comment: Neither pointers nor slices nor maps no channels _are_ reference types albeit the have reference semantic insofar as they do not "own" data stored in them.

Comment: I think it's in that loose sense the Go doc continues to use the references terminology: https://go.dev/doc/faq#references "Changing these types to act as references to the associated, shared data structures resolved these issues." I mean it is a pratical word not a strictly conceptual one.

Comment: In the loose sense it makes even less  sense to talk about heap vs. stack.